# regex python + variable

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

guys i hope you can give me  a hand with this:

Im trying to find a match on a variable value:
net_card is a string

```
net_card = salida.read()    
regex = re.compile('([a-z])\w+' % re.escape(net_card))
```

if i run this code it show me this error:

```
regex = re.compile('([a-z])\w+' % re.escape(net_card))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I haven't found a way to solve this, even with scape characters.

now if i do this:

```
net_card = salida.read()

match = re.search('([a-z])\w+', net_card)
whatIWant = match.group(1) if match else None
print whatIWant
```

it shows me just (e) in the output even when the value of net_card is NAME=ens32.

Comment: What do you think is `'([a-z])\w+' % re.escape(net_card)`? (Hint: It is not what you think, and it is the expression that causes the problem; everything else is irrelevant.)

Comment: What are you trying to match ? what did you expect the result to be for `NAME=ens32` ?

Comment: I'm trying to get ens32 part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex, `([a-z])\w+`, will match a single character in the range `a-z` as the first group, and match the rest of the string as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`. Instead, match the two groups of `\w+` (which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` in evaluation), separated by an equal sign. Here's an expression:

```
(\w+)=(\w+)
```

In practice (if you don't care about `"NAME"`), you can remove the first group and use:

```
net_card = salida.read() 
match = re.match('\w+=(\w+)', net_card)
print(match.group(1) if match else None)
```

Which will output `ens32`.